# How to use profiler in Postgres Enterprise Manager tool?

Tags: postgresql

I am watching this video. This is very good video for learning the  **Postgres Enterprise Manager tool**.
But i want to use **profiler query** in this tool. As we use profiler in sqlServer.

Below is the link for using Postgres Enterprise Manager tool. But how to enable profiler in this tool?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=huNoFF2Ohwk&t=918s

Please help me to enable the profiler tool in this **Postgres Enterprise Manager** tool.

Regards,
Abhishek

Comment: Where did you get that "Enterprise Manager tool" from? That surely has a manual that describes how to use it.

Comment: There is no way to describe the tool of profiler activity?. If any thing you know about profiler in any tool for postgrec then please provide me the way for that..
Regards,
Abhishek